# Why the `{cat,filename}` Group command with braces in Linux shell can work?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Im studying Linux.Now is reading **group command**.

Group commands in the current shell: { }

```
{ list; }
```

More in https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-brackets.html

> The semicolon (or newline) following list is required.The braces are **reserved words**, so they must be separated from the list by **blanks**.

But When I test in my Ubuntu like `{cat,2.txt}` and `{ls,-l}`

```sh
highway@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ {cat,2.txt}
This is test2!

highway@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ {ls,-l}
total 12692
-rw-rw-r-- 1 highway highway       15 Jul  2 16:49 2.txt
...
```

The both command are not separated by **blanks** and also the semicolon not following the list.
But When I follow the quote,shell told me `command not found`

```
highway@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ { ls,-l; }
ls,-l: command not found
highway@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ { cat,2.txt; }
cat,2.txt: command not found
```

In the next test,I find in non-metacharacters only `,` can success.

```sh
highway@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ {cat.2.txt}
{cat.2.txt}: command not found
highway@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ {cat_2.txt}
{cat_2.txt}: command not found
highway@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ {cat#2.txt}
{cat#2.txt}: command not found
highway@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ {cat,2.txt}
This is test2!
```

So 2 questions I want to know

1. why `{cat,2.txt}` can work without following **semicolon** and no separated by **blanks**?
   In other words,WHY the command `{cat,filename}` is parsed correctly by shell?
2. why in non-metacharacters only `,` can success?
   In other words,WHY the `,` is especial?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TL;DR Braces can also introduce [brace expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion), which are processed separately.

---

`{cat,ls}` is not a command group; it's a brace expansion. The parser can tell the difference because this is a *single* word beginning with `{`, not a command with the word `{` in command position.

The presence of the comma also indicates that this is brace expansion, rather than a single (potential) command name like `{cat.2.txt}`.

`{ cat.2.txt }` would be a command group with the command `cat.2.txt` receiving the argument `}`; the group itself is not yet closed by a `}` appearing in command position.

When `{cat,ls}` expands, it does so to two words, `cat` and `ls`, which is *then* recognized as a command `cat` and its argument `ls`.